# setPricingEngine import pyql

Tags: python, quantlib

```
european_option = VanillaOption(payoff, exercise)


spot_handle = SimpleQuote(spot_price)
flat_ts = FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_rate, day_count)
dividend_yield = FlatForward(calculation_date, dividend_rate, day_count)
flat_vol_ts = BlackConstantVol(calculation_date, cal, volatility, day_count)

bsm_process = BlackScholesMertonProcess(spot_handle, 
                                        dividend_yield, 
                                        flat_ts, 
                                        flat_vol_ts)

european_option.setPricingEngine(AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))
```

Gives the error

```
  File "qlexam.py", line 63, in <module>
    european_option.setPricingEngine(AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))
AttributeError: 'quantlib.instruments.option.VanillaOption' object has no attribute 'setPricingEngine'
```

What import do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an additional import. The reason of the error is that the pyql developers have exported some QuantLib with a different name in order to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and be more idiomatic in Python. The correct call is

```
european_option.set_pricing_engine(AnalyticEuropeanEngine(bsm_process))
```

as you can see from [this pyql example](https://github.com/enthought/pyql/blob/master/examples/american_option.py).